# Is L={0,1}* without strings that start with 00 decidable?

Tags: complexity-theory, undecidability, decision-problem

Say you have a language L = "{0,1}* without strings that start with 00". How do you prove this is decidable?  I'm drawing a blank on this one.

Comment: Your language is regular, and so decidable. You can convert a DFA accepting this language to a Turing machine accepting it, if you so desire.

Answer (score -1):

so turns out its decidable because its the regular expression $L = 01(0|1)$*

Comment: Er... That regular expression doesn't match the language you're asking about. It's close, but it's wrong.

Comment: what is the correct one then?

Comment: You're looking for strings that start with two zeroes, which isn't what your regular expression starts with.

Comment: it seems that I was wrong in the original post about the description! it should be that L accepts any string that starts with `01` over the alphabet {0,1} !

Comment: But this is the language of strings that _do_ begin with $01$, not the ones that don't.